# When I run my Python Turtle game, the Graphics Window stops responding

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am new to turtle and programming in general and wanted to make a game of tag. There are two users where one is the runner and one is the chaser (Bob and Phil). When the chaser is close to the runner (detected using the distance formula), the program sets them back to their original starting positions. However, whenever I run the program, the Turtle Graphics window freezes and stops responding, eventually leading me to close the program. Can anyone help me identify the issue?

```
import turtle
import math
bob = turtle.Turtle()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 700, height = 700)
wn.tracer()

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

bob.shape("triangle")
bob.speed(0)
bob.color("blue")
bob.penup()
bob.setpos(-50, 0)
def draw():
    bob.penup()
def nodraw():
    bob.pendown()

def fd():
    bob.fd(20)
    if bob.xcor() > 280:
        bob.setx(280)
    if bob.ycor() > 280:
        bob.sety(280)

    if bob.xcor() < -280:
        bob.setx(-280)
    if bob.ycor() <- 280:
        bob.sety(-280)
def right():
    bob.right(90)

def left():
    bob.left(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(fd, "Up")
turtle.onkey(right, "Right")

phil = turtle.Turtle()
phil.speed(0)
phil.penup()
phil.shape("triangle")
phil.color("red")
phil.setpos(50, 0)

def fdp():
    phil.fd(20)
    if phil.xcor() > 280:
        phil.setx(280)
    if phil.ycor() > 280:
        phil.sety(280)

    if phil.xcor() < -280:
        phil.setx(-280)
    if phil.ycor() <- 280:
        phil.sety(-280)
def rightp():
    phil.right(90)

def leftp():
    phil.left(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(leftp, "a")
turtle.onkey(fdp, "w")
turtle.onkey(rightp, "d")


def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False
while True:
    if isCollision(bob, phil):
        bob.setposition(-50, 0)
        phil.setposition(50, 0)



turtle.done()
```

Comment: The problem is that your 'while True' function is basically running constantly. We need to look for a way for you to run the control of the distance only after bob's position changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your original code and the suggested answers which I've tried to address below.  Specifically: you don't need to calculate the distance between turtles, they already know how to do that; your, and others, use of `tracer()` makes no sense as you've no `update()` calls; collision between Bob and Phil should be symmetrical but one of the answers considers Bob colliding with Phil but not Phil colliding with Bob; one of the answers doesn't seem to understand the nature of `turtle.done()`.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

def bob_left():
    bob.left(90)

def bob_forward():
    bob.forward(20)

    if bob.xcor() > 280:
        bob.setx(280)
    elif bob.xcor() < -280:
        bob.setx(-280)

    if bob.ycor() > 280:
        bob.sety(280)
    elif bob.ycor() < -280:
        bob.sety(-280)

    checkCollision()

def bob_right():
    bob.right(90)

def phil_left():
    phil.left(90)

def phil_forward():
    phil.forward(20)

    if phil.xcor() > 280:
        phil.setx(280)
    elif phil.xcor() < -280:
        phil.setx(-280)

    if phil.ycor() > 280:
        phil.sety(280)
    elif phil.ycor() < -280:
        phil.sety(-280)

    checkCollision()

def phil_right():
    phil.right(90)

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < 20

def checkCollision():
    if isCollision(bob, phil):
        bob.setposition(-50, 0)
        phil.setposition(50, 0)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=700, height=700)

border_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
border_pen.speed('fastest')
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.pensize(3)

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)

bob = Turtle('triangle')
bob.speed('fastest')
bob.color('blue')
bob.penup()
bob.setpos(-50, 0)

phil = Turtle('triangle')
phil.speed('fastest')
phil.color('red')
phil.penup()
phil.setposition(50, 0)

screen.onkey(bob_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(bob_forward, 'Up')
screen.onkey(bob_right, 'Right')

screen.onkey(phil_left, 'a')
screen.onkey(phil_forward, 'w')
screen.onkey(phil_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

After review, this should work:

```
import turtle
import math

bob = turtle.Turtle()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 700, height = 700)
wn.tracer()

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)

for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

bob.shape("triangle")
bob.speed(0)
bob.color("blue")
bob.penup()
bob.setpos(-50, 0)
def draw():
    bob.penup()
def nodraw():
    bob.pendown()

def fd():
    bob.fd(20)
    if bob.xcor() > 280:
        bob.setx(280)
    if bob.ycor() > 280:
        bob.sety(280)

    if bob.xcor() < -280:
        bob.setx(-280)
    if bob.ycor() <- 280:
        bob.sety(-280)
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(bob.xcor()-phil.xcor(),2)+math.pow(bob.ycor()-phil.ycor(),2))
    print(distance)
    if distance < 20:
        bob.setposition(-50, 0)
        phil.setposition(50, 0)
def right():
    bob.right(90)

def left():
    bob.left(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(fd, "Up")
turtle.onkey(right, "Right")

phil = turtle.Turtle()
phil.speed(0)
phil.penup()
phil.shape("triangle")
phil.color("red")
phil.setpos(50, 0)

def fdp():
    phil.fd(20)
    if phil.xcor() > 280:
        phil.setx(280)
    if phil.ycor() > 280:
        phil.sety(280)

    if phil.xcor() < -280:
        phil.setx(-280)
    if phil.ycor() <- 280:
        phil.sety(-280)
def rightp():
    phil.right(90)

def leftp():
    phil.left(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(leftp, "a")
turtle.onkey(fdp, "w")
turtle.onkey(rightp, "d")

turtle.done()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! The only other thing I had to do was put the collision checker under both the phil and bob functions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, new to stackoverflow, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

indent your `turtle.done()` to be inside the `while` loop. This will fix your freezing problem. like this :

```
while True:
    if isCollision(bob, phil):
        bob.setposition(-50, 0)
        phil.setposition(50, 0)
    turtle.done()
```

you could also remove the `while` loop as you don't really need it for your `if` statement to work. like this:

```
if isCollision(bob, phil):
    bob.setposition(-50, 0)
    phil.setposition(50, 0)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: The first part stopped my freezing problem is that the collision detector doesn't seem to work. And, please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I get rid of the loop, wouldn't that only allow the game to be played once?

Comment: Didn't check your collision code tbh but getting rid of the while loop won't affect the game and will keep running. I tried both code above and they worked the same.

Comment: Putting `turtle.done()` in the `while` loop makes no sense as `turtle.done()` hands off control to the tkinter event handler and doesn't return, ending the loop.  Getting rid of the `while` loop, without other modifications to compensate, effectively stops this program from doing what it's intended to do.